# Full sized background image in div?

Tags: html, css

I want a full sized background image, inside a div. The div is the last element, so I want it to fill to the bottom of the page. So far, I have this code, which makes it fill to the sides, but changing height to 100% makes it disappear, and I can't seem to get it to fill the page.

```
.launch {
    background: url('Images/launchBackground.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML of your page?

Comment: Try `background-size: contain;` maybe?

Comment: Can you have tried to reduce the background image size and repeat long the axis? Have you reduced the height attribute of div to 99% or another value close to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML, have you tried:

```
background-image: url('Images/launchBackground.jpg')
```

also you can try to set it manually:

```
.launch {
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: fixed; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the property **background-size** with the value **100% 100%**

Example:

```css
.launch {
    background: url('Images/launchBackground.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```